# Space-time bending and compression

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Is microscopic relativity correlated with macroscopic relativity?  "Small" versus "large" as it applies to relativity may not abide by the the same assumptions using current theories.  Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by “microscopic relativity” and “macroscopic relativity”? Physicists don’t generally use these terms.

Comment: Atomic versus the solar system, for example.

Comment: In mainstream physics, spacetime curvature is negligible for atoms. Gravity plays no role in atomic or molecular structure. So there is no sense in which curvatures on microscopic and macroscopic scales are either “inverse” or “equal and opposite”. Curvature is relevant on astronomical and cosmological scales and irrelevant on smaller scales (with the exception of theorized micro black holes).

Comment: unless we can measure the role gravity plays at the microscopic level how can we be sure there is "no role" even if small as it may be an additive effect over time?

Comment: I don’t think it has been measured. *In principle*, it is measurable and perhaps it will be measured someday, with better technology. The effect of curvature on, say, a hydrogen atom, *has* been studied and calculated. It is not additive over time.

Comment: In any case, measurable or not, the effect of gravity on microscopic systems is neither “inverse” to, not “equal and opposite to”, the effect of gravity on macroscopic systems. In both cases, the curvature is *proportional* to the energy-momentum of the system. Microscopic objects other than micro black holes have small energy-momentum and small curvature. Macroscopic (astronomical and larger) systems have large energy-momentum and large curvature.

Comment: Thanks.  Do black holes have microscopic properties related to atomic particles that might help explain their behavior?

Comment: For some speculation about this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_electron. These kinds of theories can be respectable enough to get published but they are not mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of gravity on microscopic systems is neither “inverse” to, not “equal and opposite” to, the effect of gravity on macroscopic systems. In both cases, the spacetime curvature is *proportional* to the energy-momentum of the system. This is the essence of the Einstein field equations,

$$G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu},$$

where the Einstein curvature tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$ sits on the left side and the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$sits on the right side, with a fixed constant of proportionality relating them.

Microscopic objects (other than micro black holes) have small energy-momentum and negligible curvature. Macroscopic (say, astronomical and larger) systems have large energy-momentum and significant curvature.

Comment: could it be that the energy-momentum of the system is not proportional in these extreme environments?

Comment: We know that Einstein's equation works well on astronomical and cosmological scales. It explains why apples fall toward Earth, the solar system, the expanding universe, gravitational wave signals from merging black holes, etc. We also know that it works fine on the atomic scale, in the sense that it says curvature is negligible there. If this were not true, our theories of atomic structure, which ignore gravity, wouldn’t work. But, in fact, they work *incredibly* well.

Comment: So the one regime in which we are not sure what happens is when you have tiny objects with extreme energy, such as micro black holes or the *very* early universe. This requires a theory of quantum gravity, and so far there is no such accepted theory.

Comment: I am not sure we really know how small is to understand fully the impacts of not understanding this would be.

Comment: Quantum gravity can kick in at different scales depending on the theory. Ten or fifteen years ago, some physicists had reasons to hope it might be relevant at the TeV scale, and that the LHC might produce one micro black hole per second! Didn't happen! Up at the Planck scale, most physicists expects quantum gravity to be important. There are many orders of magnitude in between to be uncertain about.

Comment: right, but still not a unified theory

Comment: There are multiple unified theories, but all of them have problems. If there were a unified theory that worked well and everyone agreed on, physics would be less interesting. We have lots left to discover.